# Error Sending Email using ASPEmail through SSL port 465

Tags: asp-classic

I have a problem trying to send email using ASPEmail through SSL port 465.

With another component (CDOSYS), it works normally

Error follows:

```
Transport Layer Security Error #24 (WinSock): An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.
```

Would anyone have any suggestions?

Thank´s

Comment: There's a bunch of information regarding protocols and fixes on the [ASPEmail's website](http://www.aspemail.com/whatsnew.html). Are you using the latest version? Does your server use TLS1.2 or which is the latest protocol you're using?

Comment: Hi @daniel-nordh , thanks for answering. 

I use the latest version of ASPEmail. My server uses TLS for port 587 and SSL for port 465.

I found nothing regarding this error on the developer's site.

Answer (score 0):

You need TLS1.2 as gmail and other services are now blocking sending mail without it.

Make sure you are using the latest version of ASPemail, from their news site:

"It is official: AspEmail 5.5 and AspEmail.NET 5.5 have been released.
The main new feature is support for TLS 1.2. Whenever the TLS or SSL modes are enabled, the components now use TLS 1.2 by default. TLS 1.0 can still be switched to via the TLSVersion property"